# How to get error message in Redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

How to display default error action.message in reactjs toolkit?

Got a reducer:

```
...
getQueryFail: state => {
state.loading = false
state.errors = true
}
...
```

And actions dispatch:

```
...
catch(error){
dispatch (getQueryFail())
}
....
```

How to display error message on fail action?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, it would/should be as simple as passing the `error` to the `getQueryFail` action creator. Assuming `getQueryFail` is a [`createAction`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction) action then any argument passed to it is passed in the action payload.

```
catch(error){
  dispatch (getQueryFail(error))
}
```

In the reducer access the `action.payload` to get the error.

```
getQueryFail: (state, action) => {
  state.loading = false;
  state.errors = true;
  state.error = action.payload;
}
```

It may be more clear to pass an object with `error` key though.

```
catch(error){
  dispatch (getQueryFail({ error }))
}
```

...

```
getQueryFail: (state, action) => {
  state.loading = false;
  state.errors = true;
  state.error = action.payload.error;
}
```

Comment: At the moment in browser console get  error ' A non serializable value was detected in an action, in the path : payload'

Comment: @VadymFilatov If I'm correct and this is the "error" you are trying to pass to your state then I guess you need to figure out what "error" is and access the part you need from it. It could be something like `error.message` or it could be completely convoluted, depends on what the server/API is sending back.

Comment: Sir, with *error.message* still have the issue like 'JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON.data'

Comment: @VadymFilatov Can you update your question to include what this `error` object is?